# 'module' object has no attribute 'ImageRequestOptions'

Tags: python, tableau-api

I tried to download a Tableau Workbook in as an image png-format and uses the sample from GitHub: https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/download_view_image.py using the tableauserverclient. But i get the error from above. I think I may have to Import something more, I only importet the tableauserverclient. Does anybody has an idea what I do wrong?

relevant Code:

```
import argparse
import getpass
import logging

import tableauserverclient as TSC
```

## Step 3: Query the image endpoint and save the image to the specified location

```
image_req_option = TSC.ImageRequestOptions    (imageresolution=TSC.ImageRequestOptions.Resolution.High)
    server.views.populate_image(view_item, image_req_option)
with open(args.filepath, "wb") as image_file:
    image_file.write(view_item.image)

print("View image saved to {0}".format(args.filepath))`
```

Full Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf2.test.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "pdf2.test.py", line 59, in main
    image_req_option = TSC.ImageRequestOptions(imageresolution=TSC.ImageRequestO                                                                  ptions.Resolution.High)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ImageRequestOptions'
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback and all relevant code.

Comment: Did you import it as shown in the code? `import tableauserverclient as TSC` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One key part is missing on your question, namely WHAT actually does not work (you said you get an error, but do not mention what the error says). Please edit your question :)

Comment: I edited my question and complemented my issue